# Having trouble showing that these series are the same.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^n}{n!} $$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + 1$$

*(added the +1) sorry didn't see this before, my answer guide is a poor quality photocopy

The second one is in the answer guide. The first one is my answer. The problem from the book is

> Write the taylor series for $\sin x$ centered at $\frac{\pi}{4}$

my work:

$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$f^{\prime}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$f^{\prime\prime}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$f^{\prime\prime\prime}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$f^{\left(4\right)}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$\sin x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\pi/4)}{n!}(x -\pi/4)^n$

how did the book get its answer (the second one listed at start of this question).

Comment: @Ilya what did you change?

Comment: [I changed $(n - \frac\pi4)$ into $(x-\frac\pi4)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/337906/revisions) as it certainly was not an intended typo

Comment: @Ilya, thanks, any ideas about where I went wrong?

Comment: @Ilya thanks for showing me how to get to that page. Now, I can clearly see the revisions done to my questions.  you are very helpful.

Comment: @julien Got out an enlarger glasses and it I missed the plus one. so sorry.

Comment: @MaoYiyi I put on my glasses too...see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** None of these is the Taylor series of $\sin $ at $\pi/4$...There is a problem with the sign of the coeffcients in both. Here is a safe way to get the sign: use the floor function.
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{n}}{n!}.
$$

**Previous answer**: They are not the same. The first one starts with $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+(x-\pi/4)+\ldots)$. The second one with $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}((x-\pi/4)+\ldots)$.

The second one should start at $-1$, if you want them to be equal. Adding this term and shifting your index by $1$ (i.e. replacing $n+1$ by $n$) in the second one, it becomes
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{n}}{n!}.
$$
Now
$$
\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=\frac{n^2-3n+2}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}+1-2n\equiv \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1 \;\mbox{mod}\;2.
$$
So the coefficients of the two series are indeed the same for every term of degree $n$ with $n\geq 0$.

Now the sign of the coefficients, starting from $n=0$ in the formula of the first one (the $+1$ term is artificial in the second one, and does not correspond to the formula for $n=0$), is: $-1,1,1,-1, -1, \ldots$ when it should be $1,1,-1,-1,1\ldots$.

Comment: Thanks, and I forgot the $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to be before the summation on both.  Also, am I correct?

Comment: You have missed the point - the second one, evaluated at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, is equal to zero, but should be equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: @GlenO so I just need to add one to the 2nd one and it will be correct?

Comment: Perhaps - but you said you got it from the "answer guide". Did you copy it incorrectly?

Comment: @GlenO yes, the font is very small and I didn't see it. Well, it most likely +1. poor quality photocopy.

Comment: @julien could you point me to a link/book/paper that will teach me why you wrote the mod 2.  Never have seen mod written with series before, want to know more.

Comment: The mod 2 is simply there because $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: @GlenO Good catch. I had forgotten in between that it was $\sin$ at $\pi/4$. So the first one was correct, not the second one.

Comment: @MaoYiyi We say $x\equiv y $ mod $2$ for $x,y$ integers if $2$ divides $x-y$, or if you prefer, if $x-y$ is even. Now note this is equivalent to $(-1)^x=(-1)^y$.

Answer (score 2):

Your two series I will call S1 and S2
$$n=m+1$$
$$S1 = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^n}{n!}$$
$$=\sum \limits_{m=-1}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}+1}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{(m+1)}}{(m+1)!}$$
$$=\sum \limits_{m=-1}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{(m-1)m}{2}}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{(m+1)}}{(m+1)!}$$
note how this is very simular to S2

so,
$$S1 = S2 + (-1)^{\tfrac{(c-1)c}{2}}\frac{(x-\pi/4)^{(c+1)}}{(c+1)!}~where~m=-1$$
$$S1 = S2 - 1$$